Javafx NodeOrientation does not work as expected
I'm developing an app for Arabic users so i have set:
root.setNodeOrientation(NodeOrientation.RIGHT_TO_LEFT);

This works fine when text fields contain right-to-left text, e.g., Arabic. However, it breaks the caret logic (moving the caret using keyboard left/right arrows) whenever the field contains numbers or Latin text.
Here is a demo:
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.NodeOrientation;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;


public class NodeOrientationDemo extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        TextField numbersTextField = new TextField("0123456789");
        numbersTextField.setMaxSize(80, 30);

        TextField latinTextField = new TextField("Hello");
        latinTextField.setMaxSize(80, 30);

        TextField arabicTextField = new TextField("مرحبا");
        arabicTextField.setMaxSize(80, 30);

        VBox root = new VBox(10, numbersTextField, latinTextField, arabicTextField);
        root.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        root.setNodeOrientation(NodeOrientation.RIGHT_TO_LEFT);

        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 400, 400));
        primaryStage.setTitle("NodeOrientation");
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}

Is this a known bug? And how can I solve it?
Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance!
Update 1:
I have added event filters to all the text fields and they seem to work fine. However, only the Arabic text navigation is reversed (left should be right, right should be left) my plan is to detect if it is Arabic text and based on that I will add/subtract the caret position.
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.NodeOrientation;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyCode;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;


public class NodeOrientationDemo extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        TextField numbersTextField = new TextField("0123456789");
        numbersTextField.setMaxSize(80, 30);
        keyboardNavigation(numbersTextField);

        TextField latinTextField = new TextField("Hello");
        latinTextField.setMaxSize(80, 30);
        keyboardNavigation(latinTextField);

        TextField arabicTextField = new TextField("مرحبا");
        arabicTextField.setMaxSize(80, 30);
        keyboardNavigation(arabicTextField);

        VBox root = new VBox(10, numbersTextField, latinTextField, arabicTextField);
        root.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        root.setNodeOrientation(NodeOrientation.RIGHT_TO_LEFT);

        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 400, 400));
        primaryStage.setTitle("NodeOrientation");
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private void keyboardNavigation(TextField textField) {
        textField.addEventFilter(KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED, event -> {
            if (event.getCode() == KeyCode.LEFT) {
                textField.positionCaret(textField.getCaretPosition() - 1);
                event.consume();
            } else if (event.getCode() == KeyCode.RIGHT) {
                textField.positionCaret(textField.getCaretPosition() + 1);
                event.consume();
            }
        });
    }
}

Update 2:
I have implemented the plan in update 1 and it looks good. However, one remaining issue when the text field contains both Arabic text and Latin/numbers then the behavior is a bit unclear.

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.NodeOrientation;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyCode;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;


public class NodeOrientationDemo extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        TextField numbersTextField = new TextField("0123456789");
        numbersTextField.setMaxSize(80, 30);
        keyboardNavigation(numbersTextField);

        TextField latinTextField = new TextField("Hello");
        latinTextField.setMaxSize(80, 30);
        keyboardNavigation(latinTextField);

        TextField arabicTextField = new TextField("مرحبا");
        arabicTextField.setMaxSize(80, 30);
        keyboardNavigation(arabicTextField);

        VBox root = new VBox(10, numbersTextField, latinTextField, arabicTextField);
        root.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        root.setNodeOrientation(NodeOrientation.RIGHT_TO_LEFT);

        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 400, 400));
        primaryStage.setTitle("NodeOrientation");
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private void keyboardNavigation(TextField textField) {
        textField.addEventFilter(KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED, event -> {
            final int pos = clamp(1, textField.getCaretPosition(), textField.getLength());
            final boolean isArabic = isArabicCharacter(textField.getText().charAt(pos - 1));
            if (event.getCode() == KeyCode.LEFT) {
                textField.positionCaret(textField.getCaretPosition() + (isArabic ? 1 : -1));
                event.consume();
            } else if (event.getCode() == KeyCode.RIGHT) {
                textField.positionCaret(textField.getCaretPosition() + (isArabic ? -1 : 1));
                event.consume();
            }
        });
    }

    public static boolean isArabicCharacter(char c) {
        return Character.UnicodeBlock.of(c) == Character.UnicodeBlock.ARABIC;
    }

    public static int clamp(int min, int value, int max) {
        return value < min ? min : Math.min(value, max);
    }
}


This is a long standing problem. Refer to OpenJFX 14 TextField NodeOrientation RIGHT_TO_LEFT Cannot Move Cursor Via Keyboard on Windows 10. As Jake Blues said to the Penguin in The Blues Brothers movie: I guess you're up sh#t creek

@Abra Thanks for the reply. I'll try to look for a workaround. I never tried it but maybe I can add a swing text field?

Yes, you can place Swing components in a JavaFX GUI application, however are you sure that a JTextField does not have similar problems?

@Abra you will never know until I try. However, I updated the question with useful information if you are interested. It looks like a simple problem, but they're not taking it seriously enough.

You should probably post your solution as an answer, rather than editing the question. You might also consider using a TextFormatter, which can modify changes to the text (including changes in caret position) in perhaps a more robust way that installing event filters. I haven't tried that so I don't know whether it would be cleaner or not.

@James_D Me neither. I might give it a try, however i think the answer i posted will do the job for now.

I foolishly thought update 2 (in the question) would do the trick, however, that wasn't the case. According to what I have tried, you simply cannot get rid of the "revers logic". Instead, you either have it in the Arabic text or vice versa.
The following code did the job for me:
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.NodeOrientation;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyCode;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull;


public class NodeOrientationDemo extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        TextField numbersTextField = new TextField("0123456789");
        numbersTextField.setMaxSize(80, 30);
        keyboardNavigation(numbersTextField);

        TextField latinTextField = new TextField("Hello");
        latinTextField.setMaxSize(80, 30);
        keyboardNavigation(latinTextField);

        TextField arabicTextField = new TextField("مرحبا");
        arabicTextField.setMaxSize(80, 30);
        keyboardNavigation(arabicTextField);

        VBox root = new VBox(10, numbersTextField, latinTextField, arabicTextField);
        root.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        root.setNodeOrientation(NodeOrientation.RIGHT_TO_LEFT);

        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 400, 400));
        primaryStage.setTitle("NodeOrientation");
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private void keyboardNavigation(@NotNull TextField textField) {
        textField.addEventFilter(KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED, event -> {
            final KeyCode code = event.getCode();
            if (code == KeyCode.LEFT || code == KeyCode.RIGHT) {
                boolean containsArabicText = false;
                for (char c : textField.getText().toCharArray()) {
                    if (Character.UnicodeBlock.of(c) == Character.UnicodeBlock.ARABIC) {
                        containsArabicText = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                textField.positionCaret(textField.getCaretPosition() + (containsArabicText ? 1 : -1) * (code == KeyCode.RIGHT ? -1 : 1));
                event.consume();
            }
        });
    }
}


Character directionality is considerably more complicated than just checking whether a character is in the Arabic block.  Fortunately, the java.text.Bidi class can do all of that work for you.

@VGR that's new to me i will look into it. As i said in the question i expect Arabic text in these text fields, thus i did my best to simplify things. Thanks for you comment!

@Al-Anazi, there was nothing wrong with the ideas surrounding the question you closed. Your issue is that you have a rectangle in a pane in a pane. That's causing your problem. If you make your rectangle blue, increase the size of the other two panes, and center each child, you will see the rectangle and Paths work correctly. This makes me think that you need to extend group and add your rectangle and paths directly to the group to create your node. I did not test this theory.
